# Create custom callout for an annotation

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, annotations

In iOS6 I am trying to create a custom callout for an annotation that will contain detail like, image, title, description etc. I have seen relevant posts here but aren't what I am looking for. In my app, when you are selecting an annotation, you have a choice of 4 buttons. Now I am trying to create the option for 4th button which is the detailed callout.

I have create a UIView class that represents the custom callout.

EDIT:

After help from Live2Enjoy7 I have modified my code as below.

BuildingViewController.m

```
- (void)MapMenu:(MapMenu *)menu didSelectButton:(NSInteger)index{

    if (index == 3) {

        image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
        _buildingShowCallout = YES;
        [parentView removeAnnotation:self];
        [parentView addAnnotation:self];
    }
}
```

If user press the button, this method, create new image (using url link), setting the _buildingShowCallout = YES and finally removing and adding again the selected annotation in order to make viewForAnnotation method to act.

In my MapViewController.m

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)_mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        return nil;
    }

    static NSString *identifier = @"MyAnnotation";
    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [_mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

    BuildingViewController* building = (BuildingViewController*) annotation;

    // If a new annotation is created
    if (annotationView == nil) {

        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:building reuseIdentifier:identifier];

        if (building.buildingShowCallout) {// Create the custom callout
            BuildingCallOut* buildingCallout = [[BuildingCallOut alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 150)];
            [buildingCallout showCallout:building];
            [annotationView addSubview:buildingCallout];//add the new callout as subview of the selected annotation.
        }

    } else{

        annotationView.annotation = annotation;

        if (building.buildingShowCallout) {// Create the custom callout
            BuildingCallOut* buildingCallout = [[BuildingCallOut alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 150)];
            [buildingCallout showCallout:building];
            [annotationView addSubview:buildingCallout];//add the new callout as subview of the selected annotation.
        }
    }

    return annotationView;
}
```

That's working fine BUT now I have one new problem.

1. If you select to see a callout for one annotation and then select to see a callout for another annotation, the previous one stays on the map. How I can solve this?

Screenshot
![enter image description here][1]

As you can see.. the previous callout on the top of the screen remains when I am calling the new one at the bottom. Struggling to find where to put the "disappear" line.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your BuildingViewController is your MapViewController.

You want to declare it as an MKMapViewDelegate in your header. This will give you access to several methods that will allow you to change the view of the annotation that appears and even the pin.

First, import MapKit/MapKit.h and UIKit/UIKit.h if you aren't already.

Second, declare that your BuildingViewController conforms to the MKMapViewDelegate protocol (as stated above).

Third, declare your BuildingViewController as the map view's delegate in ViewDidLoad like:

```
self.mapView.delegate=self; //assuming that the you have a MKMapView named MapView in your layout
```

Fourth, implement these protocol methods:

```
-(MKAnnotationView*)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation;

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view;
```

First method allows you to set right and left call out accessories as well as modify bunch of other things (this is where you want to do you CGRectMakes).

In second method, you decide what data actually gets displayed in the annotation view.

Search the documentation for MKMapViewDelegate --> [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html)

Comment: Thank you for reply. My mistake was that didn't make it clear enough. BuildingViewController is not MapViewController. Represents a single annotation and stores info like, name, description, coordinates etc. I have another class called MapViewController that generates a bunch of BuildingViewController objects and then place them on the map. I am already using both methods that you have mentioned. I am not interested in right and left accessories as I want to display full info when user select annotation. Could you please give more detail on '(this is where you want to do you CGRectMakes)'?

Comment: Live2Enjoy7 your answer really helped me to clear stuff in my mind. I will update the post with what I have modified and what I have achieved. However, I am facing two minor problems now as I am mentioning in my updated post. Thanks again.

Comment: can you post a screen shot of what it looks like right now and one of how you want it to look like?

Comment: I have noticed that each time the new buildingCallout object is taking as starting position it's annotation (0,0). I was confused because my previous solution was based on the current mapview. Now, if I have static values is close to what I want. Still suffering with the 2nd problem however. The old buildingCallout, remains on the screen.

Comment: yes, generally in making the view for annotation you have to use static values. again a pic is worth a thousand words, if you post a screenshot it'll be much easier

Comment: Ok I think I know what the issue is, you are inserting everything into the view in -(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)_mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation method. This method is only for setup of the view, not actually putting stuff into the view. The putting of stuff into the view happens in -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view method. This is where you want to link all thumbnails, titles etc. This is why you have the old annotation pop up when clicking on the pin.

Comment: a bit tough to tell you what to put into each of the methods because I don't know your exact setup, but follow the strategy of creating the structure in viewForAnnotation (you can set things to nil here) and then filling that structure in didSelectAnnotationView

Comment: You may not know the exact code but your comment on general strategy has helped me to clear all these in my mind. You are right, my issue was that, everything appeared in the viewForAnnotation. Is my first try on custom callout stuff and I can say has confused me a lot. Now, I believe I can move on. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Glad to hear, if my answers have helped please hit the V :)